# Append values from one row to a new column in a separate row

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

In my dataframe, I have two rows that are related by a variable 'groupID'. Specifically, the related rows have an identical groupID value (e.g., both rows have a value of 5).

I would like to take specific values from the related rows and append the values of interest into new columns on the related row. Explained another way: if row 1 and row 4 are related (because they share a groupID), I would like to take the value from column A in row 1 and append it to a new column in row 4. At the same time, I would like to take the value from column A in row 4 and append it to the new column in row 1. To distinguish the new column names from the original column names, I would like to add a suffix to the new column (e.g. columnA_teammate). I haven't attempted this because I don't know where to start.

In the sample data provided below, I would like to complete the manipulation described above for columnA and columnB, but not for columnC.

```
df <- 
  data.frame(personID = c(1:16),
         groupID = c(1:8),
         columnA = rnorm(16, mean = 4, sd = 1),
         columnB = seq(2,32,by=2),
         columnC = rbinom(16, 1, .7)
         )
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What happens if there are more than two related rows?

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- 
  data.frame(personID = c(1:16),
             groupID = c(1:8),
             columnA = rnorm(16, mean = 4, sd = 1),
             columnB = seq(2,32,by=2),
             columnC = rbinom(16, 1, .7)
  )

fchange = function(data) tibble(column4 = c(data$columnA[2], data$columnA[1]))

df1 = df %>% group_by(groupID) %>% 
  nest(data=!contains("groupID")) %>% 
  mutate(col4 = map(data, fchange)) %>% 
  unnest(c(data, col4)) %>% arrange(personID )
```

output

```
# A tibble: 16 x 6
# Groups:   groupID [8]
   groupID personID columnA columnB columnC column4
     <int>    <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>   <dbl>
 1       1        1    2.98       2       0    5.06
 2       2        2    2.83       4       0    4.92
 3       3        3    3.84       6       1    4.54
 4       4        4    4.52       8       1    6.29
 5       5        5    3.07      10       0    4.52
 6       6        6    2.64      12       0    3.20
 7       7        7    3.95      14       1    4.64
 8       8        8    5.24      16       1    3.17
 9       1        9    5.06      18       1    2.98
10       2       10    4.92      20       1    2.83
11       3       11    4.54      22       1    3.84
12       4       12    6.29      24       1    4.52
13       5       13    4.52      26       1    3.07
14       6       14    3.20      28       1    2.64
15       7       15    4.64      30       1    3.95
16       8       16    3.17      32       1    5.24
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  left_join(df, by = "groupID", suffix = c("", "_teammate")) %>% 
  filter(personID != personID_teammate) %>% 
  select(-personID_teammate, -columnC_teammate)
```

returns

```r
   personID groupID  columnA columnB columnC columnA_teammate columnB_teammate
1         1       1 4.162857       2       1         5.492979               18
2         2       2 4.377751       4       0         4.232240               20
3         3       3 4.721330       6       1         6.116825               22
4         4       4 5.372810       8       0         6.111737               24
5         5       5 5.260699      10       1         2.649022               26
6         6       6 4.055667      12       0         2.569150               28
7         7       7 1.913988      14       1         3.810043               30
8         8       8 1.643768      16       0         4.905459               32
9         9       1 5.492979      18       0         4.162857                2
10       10       2 4.232240      20       1         4.377751                4
11       11       3 6.116825      22       1         4.721330                6
12       12       4 6.111737      24       1         5.372810                8
13       13       5 2.649022      26       1         5.260699               10
14       14       6 2.569150      28       1         4.055667               12
15       15       7 3.810043      30       1         1.913988               14
16       16       8 4.905459      32       1         1.643768               16
```

#### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(personID = 1:16, groupID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), columnA = c(4.1628566514354, 
4.37775120677026, 4.72132999511972, 5.37280989644003, 5.2606991455534, 
4.05566700843516, 1.91398769391631, 1.6437683999418, 5.49297883127052, 
4.23224045206759, 6.11682482265615, 6.11173734702799, 2.64902184119363, 
2.5691503674088, 3.81004257186055, 4.90545868691805), columnB = c(2, 
4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32), columnC = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```